# JSF tags not rendering after update page to use new namespace xmlns.jcp.org

Tags: java, maven, jsf, jsf-2

I have a maven webapp project that runs on tomcat 8.
If i use the old namespace `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html` it works fine, but with the new one the JSF tags are not rendered after viewing it on browser.
These are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is my faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
</faces-config>
```

What am i doing wrong?

**---UPDATE---**
This is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: how did you configure your FacesServlet ?

Answer (score 1):

try version 3.1 with new namespace:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```